# Error accessing js from node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, express

I am a newbie for nodejs, Kindly excuse me.
I have created a node js server app and the html was served using expressjs as follows

```
app.use(express.static( 'public/js'));
app.use(express.static( 'public/css'));
app.use(express.static( 'public/img'));

res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname +  "/public" + "/login.html"));
```

In the client side 
 The JS was included in head tag as

```
<script src="fingerprint.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The inline JS in the body tag is

```
var bid = new Fingerprint();
document.getElementById('bid').value = bid.get();
console.log("----"+bid.get());
document.write('Hello');
```

Here if I run this HTML from the node server, the inline JS was not working, where as if I run in the file mode ie file:///login.html everything is working fine.

Comment: Which directory is fingerprint.js located in?

Comment: The path is /public/js/

Comment: @Zeke Sinder Thanks for your kind participation, It is doing good and It was the problem with the browser plugin. The code is fine with no errors.

Comment: Good to hear 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
/* jshint ignore:start */
// app.js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

// Root path redirect
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/public" + "/login.html"));
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))
```

Here's what my directory structure looks like (checkout the left pane):
[image: VS Code Screenshot]

The HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="/js/fingerprint.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- HTML Content  -->
    <div id="bid"></div>
    <!-- Inline JS -->
    <script>
        var bid = new Fingerprint();
        document.getElementById('bid').value = bid.get();
        console.log("The Bid Value: " + bid.get());
        // document.write('Hello');
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Finally, the fingerprint.js file:

```
/* jshint ignore:start */
class Fingerprint {
    get() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

I can see the `Fingerprint` object loading correctly:

[image: Chrome Dev Tools]

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks @benSooraj, The problem was the noscript plugin which was installed in FF.